# ISAPI Hikvision dar de alta rostro

Tags: nodejs

Estoy intentando agregar un rostro a una persona, pero simplemente me responde con un

```
{
    "statusCode": 5,
    "statusString": "Invalid Format",
    "subStatusCode": "badJsonFormat",
    "errorCode": 1342177282,
    "errorMsg": "unknow"
}
```

La uri quee utilizo es `/ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json`

```
let formData = new FormData()

    
            formData.append('FaceDataRecord', JSON.stringify({ 
                faceLibType: faceLibType.replace(/'/g, '"'), 
                FDID: FDID.replace(/'/g, '"'), 
                FPID: FPID.replace(/'/g, '"')
            }));
           
           formData.append('faceUrl', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path))
         
          const cliente = new DigestClient(process.env.USERNAME_FACIAL, process.env.PASSWORD_FACIAL, { algorithm: 'MD5' })

            const response = await cliente.fetch(URL_ADD_FACE, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                maxBodyLength: Infinity,
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml'
                }
            })

             const json = await response.json();

             return res.json(json)
```